# How do I get the console to print out the name, keeping in mind the name variable isn't constant?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a ternary expression that decides what to do if the user enters a name or not. If the user enters a name — like 'Jane' — use string interpolation to log Hello, Jane! to the console. Otherwise, simply log Hello!. I don't want to hard code Jane to check for truthiness, rather be able to input any name and be able to print out the same. Any input is much appreciated.

```
    let userName = '';

    userName === true ? console.log(`Hello, ${userName}!`) : console.log('Hello!');
```

Comment: `userName.length > 0` ?

Comment: What do you mean with `I don't want to hard code Jane to check for truthiness`?  And why don't you use `userName ? console.log(\`Hello, ${userName}!\`) : console.log('Hello!');`?

Comment: Btw. what is the reason that you want to use a _ternary expression_? There are only rare occasions when ternary expressions should be used, in most cases they make the code hard to read and understand.

Comment: That worked! Got what you meant @Yoshi thanks a ton.

Comment: @t.niese Gotcha. Been doing a course on Codecademy and this one was one of the problem sets.

Comment: @helloworldio I don't know Codecademy but if it teaches you things like `userName ? console.log(\`Hello, ${userName}!\`) : console.log('Hello!');` without mentioning that this is a really bad coding style, then I would be concerned that it is not a good site, for learining.

Comment: As soon as you start to have other operators or many tokens in between the `?` and then `:`  like `(`, `)`, `.`, … and the expression between `?` and `:` or after the `:` get really long it is hard to see what belongs to the ternary, and what isn't. And that is horrible for code reviews and maintainability.

Comment: @t.niese Codecademy seems very legit. They seem to explain the concepts well. However, I'll keep what you said in mind. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @helloworldio There are always some smaller parts that can become pitfalls are make code inconsistent. E.g. they show this [Truthy and Falsy Assignment](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/introduction-to-javascript/lessons/control-flow/exercises/truthy-falsy-operators), with this example `let defaultName = username || 'Stranger';`. This is a pattern that widely used, but still problematic and can fail horribly in certain use-cases. If you e.g. have something like `let count = inCount || 1;` and you want to allow also having a count of `0`. Whenever you see _short-hand_ you should be carefull.